# Using icon in css files by pseudo element

Tags: css

How I Can Use Icons From "Font Awesome" As Pseudo Element As "After Or Before"
I Try Do This A lot but It didn't work

Comment: please share your attempt [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can add icons using Font Awesome Cheat Sheet. https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/cheatsheet/

Here is an example how you can do that.

```
.icon
{
content: '\&#xf1d1;'
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
a:before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: "\f095";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<a href="#">Call Us</a>

</body>
</html>
```